# Which one is in good order?

Tags: word-order

I would like ask Native English person.
Which one is natural?

## Welcome Guide JAPAN

## JAPAN Welcome Guide

## Welcome JAPAN Guide

Comment: Is this a naming request?

Comment: None of them are comfortable, colloquial phrases. If I were writing a guide for tourists I would _classify_ it as a 'guide' but I would _title_ it 'Welcome to Japan'.

Comment: It depends what your guide is about. Is it for people who travel to Japan? In this case I would say 'The Welcome to Japan Guide' or simply 'Welcome to Japan'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it _is_ a naming request; the requested title will be beyond headlinese.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a **Welcome Guide** ***to Japan***, or it could be a ***Japanese*** **Welcome Guide**.

If you use **Japan**, you need an additional word so that the phrase makes sense. But if you use **Japanese** it *may* mean that it's written in Japanese—although not necessarily. (A Japanese candy, for instance, is a candy that's from Japan.)

Comment: Dear Jason Bassford-san!!

Thank you for your advise:) It is very helpful!!